# Existence of solution to linear boundary value problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request, boundary-value-problem, initial-value-problems

Consider a differential equation of the form
$$
\dot \gamma(t)=F_t(\gamma(t))
$$
For $\gamma:[0,1]\to \mathbb R^{2n}$ and a smooth $F:[0,1]\times \mathbb R^{2n}\to \mathbb R^{2n}$ such that every $F_t$ is *affine* linear.

Then for every initial value $x_o\in\mathbb R^{2n}$ there exists a unique solution $\gamma$ with $\gamma(0)=x_0$. (right?)

But what about solutions with **boundary values on the first $n$ components**? Does there exists a solution with
$$
\gamma(0)_i=0=\gamma(1)_i \text{ for } i=1,\dots,n?
$$

---

**Rephrased:**
Consider the map
$$E:\mathbb R^{2n}\to \mathbb R^{2n},x_0\mapsto \gamma_{x_0}(1)$$
where $\gamma_{x_0}$ is the unique solution with $\gamma_{x_0}(0)=x_0$. Now what is the image $E(\{0\}^n\times \mathbb R^n)$? Does it intersect $\{0\}^n\times \mathbb R^n$?

---

**Context**: This question comes from reducing a second order linear DE to a first order linear DE. There I want a solution of this 2nd order DE given $\gamma(0)$ and $\gamma(1)$ as opposed to given the initial conditions $\gamma(0)$ and $\dot \gamma(0)$. (Sometimes called "Two-Endpoint problem")

---

I dont know anything about theory of differential equations; Any keywords or pointers to what to look for are appreciated

---

Edit: Just found this: [When do boundary conditions specify a unique solution to ODEs?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2387989/when-do-boundary-conditions-specify-a-unique-solution-to-odes?rq=1)

Comment: Does $F_t$ have a specific structure besides being affine (i.e. $F_t(x)=A_tx+b_t$)?